# Appropriate to use group-based trajectory modelling on variable with only 2 or 3 time points?

Tags: categorical-data, panel-data

Is it possible to do an analysis similar to group-based trajectory modelling (GBTM) with a categorical variable measured only over few time points (2 or 3)? We wanted to classify individuals based on a behavioral variable measured before and during an event and originally were inspired by these kinds of analysis:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41654923_Group-Based_Trajectory_Modeling_in_Clinical_Research

However, these methods seem to be designed for data with many more time points than we have. I couldn't find an explicit statement of minimum number of time points required, but I infer GBTM is not appropriate for data with only 2 or 3 time points. Is this the case? And if so, is there a more appropriate method for a categorical variable (e.g., none, low, moderate, high) measured at 2 or 3 time points? The goal is to see if there are natural groupings of individuals that emerge based on their behavior at T1 and change in behavior to T2 (and in some cases T3).

Any suggestions for appropriate approaches would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

GBTM is just an extension of mixture modelling/latent class analysis. Technically you could do it without repeated observations at all (if you have heterogeneous time point collections, e.g. used age instead of T1, T2, T3).

With fixed temporal periods like you have here, with one period you could look at changes in the intercept, with two could look at changes in intercept + slope, and with three could look at an additional quadratic term.

But here given the fixed time points, and the limited nature of the dependent variable, your model I'm guessing is likely to be fully saturated. For example if you looked at a quadratic term and included enough mixture components, it would be equivalent to just tabulating up all the potential permutations of your data. (Which is probably what I would suggest you do here anyway IMO.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was wondering if using all the combinations of the categories would be just as useful and much simpler in this case. Unfortunately the data ended up being much more limited than was originally hoped. Sometimes the data just don't support the ambitious analysis plan!